# express error when I execure npm run start

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am getting an error when I execute

**npm run start** (node bin/index.js)

when I compile using gulp scripts is working fine without errors.

My **gruntfile.js** is:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const JSON_FILES = ['src/*.json', 'src/**/*.json'];

// pull in the project TypeScript config
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('scripts', () => {
  const tsResult = tsProject.src()
  .pipe(tsProject());
  return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['scripts'], () => {
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.ts', ['scripts']);
});

gulp.task('assets', function() {
  return gulp.src(JSON_FILES)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('bin'));
});
```

my **tsconfig.json** is:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "bin/",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": [],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,  
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],   
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/index.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

my index.ts is:

```
import * as http from 'http';
import * as debug from 'debug';

import App from './App'

//debug('ts-express:server');

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 8080);


App.set('port', port);


const server = http.createServer(App)
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val: number|string): number|string|boolean {
  let port: number = (typeof val === 'string') ? parseInt(val, 10) : val;
  if (isNaN(port)) return val;
  else if (port >= 0) return port;
  else return false;
}

function onError(error: NodeJS.ErrnoException): void {

  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') throw error;

  let bind = (typeof port === 'string') ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

  switch(error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(`${bind} requires elevated privileges`);
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(`${bind} is already in use`);
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening(): void {
  let addr = server.address();
  let bind = (typeof addr === 'string') ? `pipe ${addr}` : `port ${addr.port}`;
  debug(`Listening on ${bind}`);
}
```

the imports files when I write in console **npm run start** doesnt transform in require.

**The errors are**:

npm run start

> back-new@1.0.0 start C:\Users\XXXX\back-new
>   node bin/index.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'App'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object. (C:\Users\David M\source\repos\CV_Development\cv_backend\nodejs\back-new\bin\index.js:2:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! back-new@1.0.0 start: `node bin/index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the back-new@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-03T22_34_00_257Z-debug.log

**index.js** is:

```
var http = require("http");
var App = require("App");

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 8080);
App.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(App);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = (typeof val === 'string') ? parseInt(val, 10) : val;
    if (isNaN(port))
        return val;
    else if (port >= 0)
        return port;
    else
        return false;
}
function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen')
        throw error;
    var bind = (typeof port === 'string') ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + " is already in use");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}
function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = (typeof addr === 'string') ? "pipe " + addr : "port " + addr.port;
    debug("Listening on " + bind);
}
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Can you post what your transpiled `bin\index.js` looks like?

Comment: sorry, I was bussy and I couldnt answer you before. I set index.js

Comment: Do you have `App.js` on a same folder level as `bin/index.js`?

Comment: Yup ^. Looks like your `App.js` may be in a different directory? Also shouldn't your `index.js` say `var App = require("./App");` or `var App = require("../dist/App");` or wherever your `App.js` file is located? Paths starting without `/`, `./`, `../` are resolved to `node_modules/`